# Error when converting bash code to snakefile

Tags: indexing, pipeline, snakemake, generate

I want to generate genome index by using STAR. The bash code works in the terminal but I want to convert it to snakefile.

This is the bash code:

```sh
STAR --runThreadN 4 --runMode genomeGenerate --genomeDir star --genomeFastaFiles Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.22.dna.toplevel.fa --sjdbGTFfile bdgp6/Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.95.gtf
```

After running the bash code it generates more then one file in the star directory. One of the files is called `genomeParameters.txt`, I need this file for further use.

In snakemake:

```py
rule index:
    input:
       fasta = "Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.22.dna.toplevel.fa"
       gtf = "bdgp6/Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.95.gtf"

    output:
        "star"
    shell:
        " STAR --runThreadN 4 --runMode genomeGenerate --genomeDir {output} --genomeFastaFiles {input.fasta} --sjdbGTFfile {input.gtf}"
```

The ERROR:

```
SyntaxError in line 10 of /data/storix2/student/Thema11/dme/projectThema11/generateGenomeIndex:
Command must be given as string after the shell keyword. (generateGenomeIndex, line 10)
```

Comment: This exception comes from the parser, but I see no issue excep of missing comma in between the input files. Please confirm that the code provided is exact copy/paste of the program you run.

Comment: I just added a comma between the parameters but the error still appears. @DmitryKuzminov

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that helps to reproduce the issue. I guess that what we can see in your question is not what you actually run.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov The code shown above is actually what I am running. But I just solved the problem! The error was caused by the indents.

Comment: Running snakemake with [flag `--printshellcmds` or `-p`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#OUTPUT) to print resolved shell command might help.

Comment: I also encountered this error after I make some editings to my snakemake file. In my case it is caused by inconsistency in using tab or spaces for indentation. I think snakemake handles this really poorly and has caused a lot of trouble for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma after the first input file:

```
input:
   fasta = "Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.22.dna.toplevel.fa",
   gtf = "bdgp6/Drosophila_melanogaster.BDGP6.95.gtf"
```

However, the error you are seeing isn't the error I usually get when that comma is missing. I wonder if the space at the beginning of the command is causing the problem. You could also try removing it:

```
shell:
    "STAR --runThreadN 4 --runMode genomeGenerate --genomeDir {output} --genomeFastaFiles {input.fasta} --sjdbGTFfile {input.gtf}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error after removing the space and adding a comma between the input parameters.

Comment: @Mar (late reply) it could be just a case of mixed spaces and tabs as indentations.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation I used when writing in vscode was spaces, and then when I changed it on the cluster and wrote tab I ran into this problem, but when I changed tab to spaces the problem was solved.